# Is there any way that , I can disable other participant video in kurento group call?

Tags: browser, webrtc, kurento, peer, signaling

I am working on a application in which an admin can disable/enable the video of any participant.
is there any way that i can disable other participant video in kurento group call except my own video ? kindly help me i am newbie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable/disable the video of participants(not our own) in kurento many-to-many call(group call) .?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529270/how-to-enable-disable-the-video-of-participantsnot-our-own-in-kurento-many-to)