# How to enable/disable the video of participants(not our own) in kurento many-to-many call(group call) .?

Tags: call, webrtc, kurento

I am working on the Kurento and I am using many-to-many tutorial(group call) Now i want to mute(disable) only the video of the participants(not my own) in the room but their audio should remain enabled.Also I should be able to enable/disable the video as many time as i want.?

Kindly help.I am new in webrtc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from javascript by using

```
participants[name].rtcPeer.videoEnabled = false;
```

You can do this by using following java code

```
user1OutgoingMedia.disconnect(user2IncomingMedia, MediaType.VIDEO);
```

Comment: I have tried this line
participants[name].rtcPeer.videoEnabled = false;
but this is not working 
if i give the name of my own this works but if i give the name of other user this does not work.

Comment: Host/admin will click on some button to disable video of user "xyz" , on this click Host/admin will send a websocket message to that user "xyz" via signalling server, and then that user "xyz" will do `participants["xyz"].rtcPeer.videoEnabled = false;`

Comment: thanks a lot Sagar Pilkhwal.Can you please help me that how can i disable just video in kurento (many-to-many) call for all participants.I want just audio no video.

Comment: just follow the steps I mentioned in the previous comment this will disable only VIDEO

Answer (score 0):

```
localMS.audioTracks.get(i).setEnabled(false);
```

Here `localMs` is Local MediaStream

Comment: thanks.I am working in kurento.Is this kurento syntax?

Comment: Code is for Android application